# What's the best approach for building a dynamic web pages with signal r and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm currently using asp.net MVC .net core 3.1 with signal r to build a website. However one of the things that takes the longest is writing the code for building dynamic html elements. For example, i'm using the following javascript:

```
function generateScheduleInfoRow(category, emplName, emplSendTestReport, empldSendBoe, emplEmail, emplPhoneNum, emplid, emplDeptNum) {
    var output = `
            <td> 
                <input name="category" type="text" value="` + category + `"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="emplName` + currentScheduleInfoRows +`" name="emplName" value="` + emplName + `" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="emailPersonalCalendar" value="0"><input type="checkbox" onclick="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" value="` + emplSendTestReport + `" name="emplSendTestReport" value="0"><input type="checkbox" onclick="this.previousSibling.value=1-this.previousSibling.value">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="emplEmail` + currentScheduleInfoRows + `" name="emplEmail" value="` + emplEmail + `" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="emplPhoneNum` + currentScheduleInfoRows +`"  name="emplPhoneNum" value="` + emplPhoneNum + `" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="emplId` + currentScheduleInfoRows +`"  name="emplid" value="` + emplid + `" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="emplDeptNum` + currentScheduleInfoRows +`"  name="emplDeptNum" value="` + emplDeptNum + `" type="text" />
            </td>`;
    currentScheduleInfoRows++;
    return output;
}
```

This function helps to build a row in a table. I receive some JSON data from a signal r connection and use that to dynamically construct the table:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < dataJson["schedulePeople"].length; i++) {
        var cur = dataJson["schedulePeople"][i];
        document.getElementById("eventDetailsTable").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = generateScheduleInfoRow(cur["Category"], cur["EntityName"], cur["EmailTestReport"], cur["EmailBoe"],
            cur["EmailAddr"], cur["PhoneNum"], cur["Emplid"], cur["DeptNum"]);
    }
```

Is there a better technique or framework or methodology or open source code for building these HTML pages quickly? I use this same kind of code technique all over my website. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around for a while I recommend using microsoft's new Blazor:

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)!

Blazor lets you easily generate razor pages and html elements with C# like code. It uses signalr in the background to facilitate this. All signal r invocations are abstracted away.